# SQL Union Or Join Horizantally

Tags: sql-server, join, count, union

I am trying to get the below queries into one row on a query.  Below is just an example, I have about 10 counts to combine into one row

```
select ISNULL(COUNT(*),0) as ENGLAND from Service_User s 
where s.commissioner_id ='1'

select ISNULL(COUNT(*),0) as WALES from Service_User s 
where s.commissioner_id ='2'

select ISNULL(COUNT(*),0) as GERMANY from Service_User s 
where s.commissioner_id ='3'
```

I have tried to UNION them but they appear vertically and I want them horizontally.

I would like it to appear like below

[image]

Comment: You don't have to use `ISNULL(COUNT(*),0)` just `COUNT(*)` will return 0 if no records are found...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Use `Sub-select`

```
SELECT (SELECT Isnull(Count(*), 0)
        FROM   Service_User s
        WHERE  s.commissioner_id = '1') AS ENGLAND,
       (SELECT Isnull(Count(*), 0)
        FROM   Service_User s
        WHERE  s.commissioner_id = '2') AS WALES,
       (SELECT Isnull(Count(*), 0)
        FROM   Service_User s
        WHERE  s.commissioner_id = '3') AS GERMANY
```

Comment: i think ,this query will be lot slower .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sql Server 2012 or above then it can be shorter .

Try this,

```
;With CTE As

(
select commissioner_id, ROW_NUMBER()Over(Partition By commissioner_id order by commissioner_id) RowNum  from Service_User s 
 s.commissioner_id  in(1,2,3)

)
,CTE1 as
(
 Select commissioner_id,MAX(RowNum) from CTE
 group By commissioner_id
)

select * from CTE
--pivot this result set
```

Answer (score 0):

If I knew for fact that my commissioner_id's were not doing to change and I could load the values to pivot on into the query I would go with option 1.

```
SELECT * FROM (select COUNT(*) As Count,(select case commissioner_id when '01' then 'England' when '02' then 'Wales' when '03' then 'Germany' else 'Other') as [Location] from Service_User group by [Location]) as s PIVOT (SUM(count) FOR [Location] IN ("England","Wales","Germany","Other")) AS PivotOut
```

Second Option I would create a stored procedure that dynamically loaded the options for commissioner_id and then pivoted. This way as the commissioner_ids are added there is no manual intervention to return the required results.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[DynamicSP]
AS
BEGIN
    declare @sql as varchar(max)
    declare @dynamic varchar(max)

    select @dynamic=COALESCE(@dynamic +',','')+commissioner_id
    FROM 
    (select distinct commissioner_id from Service_User) as CommIds order by commissioner_id

    set @SQL = '(select COUNT(*) As count,commissioner_id as [Location] from Service_User group by [Location]) as s PIVOT (SUM(count) FOR [Location] IN (' + @dynamic + ')) AS PivotOut'

    exec(@sql)
END
```